# Facebook graph api DfsException: I fail at picking lvols

Tags: facebook, api

I got this exception from php Facebook api call in unchanged code which was OK in previous days:

**DfsException: I fail at picking lvols :(**

Can anyone help or explain what it means?

Comment: Getting same problem today too. Haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's Tuesday, when FB pushes most of their new code, so should be resolved soon. There's an open [ticket](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/448760731816423?browse=search_4fb1e1adcdcb31d85533405).